# The inserted row take the same value

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I use repository with Entity Framework to insert Tasks and its dependencies and deliverable from type Task  .....`item.Depens` list of int values.

The problem is data in `newdependicies` list the `DependingOnTaskID` take value of `TaskID`

```
public IHttpActionResult Add(TaskViewModel item)
{
    try
    {
        var _item = new Task { Name = item.Title,Description  = item.Descrip,JobID=item.jopId ,};
        _unitOfWork.TaskRepository.Add(_item);
        _unitOfWork.TaskRepository.Commit();
        var newDeliverables = new List<TaskDeliverable>();
        foreach (var i in item.Delivs)
        {
           var existingTask = _unitOfWork.TaskRepository.FindBy(i);
            if (existingTask != null)
            {
                var dl = new TaskDeliverable() { DeliveredToTaskD=i ,TaskID = _item.ID };
                newDeliverables.Add(dl);
            }
        }
        var newdependicies = new List<TaskDependency>();

        foreach (var i in item.Depens)
        {
            var existingTask = _unitOfWork.TaskRepository.FindBy(i);
            if (existingTask != null)
            {
                var de = new TaskDependency() { DependingOnTaskID=i ,TaskID=_item.ID};
                newdependicies.Add(de);
            }
        }
        _item.TaskDependencies = newdependicies;
        _item.TaskDeliverables = newDeliverables;
        _unitOfWork.TaskRepository.Update(_item.ID, _item);
        _unitOfWork.TaskRepository.Commit();
        item.ID = _item.ID;
        return Ok(item);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string errorId = ex.LogElmah();
        var message = Utilities.WebApiError(1, Common.Constants.SystemErrorMessage, errorId);
        return BadRequest(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Gert Arnold   that what i exactly want  the problem in  "DependingOnTaskID="  it  take the Task IdG  too  in  TaskDependencies  only

Comment: There is too much unknown in your code. Like, what is the content of `item.Depens`?